Why do my quotes need a “space” to be correctly typed with a “US - International PC” keyboard layout in macOS?
Whenever I type a quote or double quote, I need to press "space". For instance, let's suppose I want to type "user", I type the double quote " and then u and the result is not "u but a ü, and that's not what I want.
I made a video explaining it.
My keyboard layout is US - International PC.
I do want to be able to type ü and é, but I was used to do this using option+e and option+u. I want my quotes to be just quotes.
How to do that?

International keyboard layouts (Mac, Linux and Windows) use those as dead keys: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key . Use another layout -- easily switched with a keypress.

As per this Q/A you can use QWERTY US (ANSI) to avoid such effect. Similar to Windows where it work on your way with UK English.
